# Powershell Script to check if Active Directory User Last Logon

Tags: powershell, authentication

I'm trying to write a powershell script that accepts an username as an argument, and displays the last logon time of the user. If the user has not logged in before, the message `has not logged in before` should be displayed.

For example, if you run `.\lastlogon -username marywong` the message is displayed:

> marywong last logon time 13/07/2017

If you run `.\lastlogon -username guest`, I get the message:

> guest has not logged in before

Below is my code, however it doesn't seem to be looping into the else loop when the user has not logged in before.

```
param (
    [string]$username
)

$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $username} | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon

$lastlogontime = $user.lastlogon

If ($user -ne $Null) {
    if($user.LastLogon -gt $time) {
        $displaylastlogon = [datetime]::FromFileTime($lastlogontime)
        Write-Host  $username " last logon time" $displaylastlogon 
    }
    else {
        $displaylastlogon = [datetime]::FromFileTime($lastlogontime)
        Write-Host  $username " has not logged in before"
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host  $username " does not exist"
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether $null is returned for a user who hasn't logged on before?

Answer (score 1):

There is information to be gained from using `Get-ADUser` and `Get-ADObject` separately. If the user has never logged in, they are still a user that exists. That is different from a user that does not exist.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string]$username
)

$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $username}
if ($user -ne $null) {
    $userlogon = $user | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon
    if ($userlogon.LastLogon -ne $null) {
        $lastlogontime = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($userlogon.LastLogon)
        Write-Host  $username " last logon time" $lastlogontime
    } else {
        Write-Host  $username " has not logged in before"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host  $username " does not exist"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the lastLogon you get a format that AD uses...
then when the if is running you get

```
Could not compare "131820853335016078" to "09/24/2018 18:18:57". Error: "Cannot convert value "9/24/2018 6:18:57 PM" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int64'.""
```

so it's not getting to the else..

try using the LastLogonDate property, it will help you more.

try to use this:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $username} -Properties LastLogonDate

$lastlogontime = $user.lastlogonDate
```

Edit:

you have some more issues with you code:

1. You need to remove the displaylastlogon
2. you cant use -gt because it will always be false.. the user cant log in the future.. you need to use -lt

here is the full script, working:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $username} -Properties LastLogonDate

$lastlogontime = $user.lastlogonDate

If ($user -ne $Null) {

if($lastlogontime -lt $time)
    {
          Write-Host  $username " last logon time" $lastlogontime 
    }

    else

    {
          Write-Host  $username " has not logged in before"
    }
}

else

    {
      Write-Host  $username " does not exist"
    }
```

Another Edit:

I just notice that its not answering the case when user never logon, because you will get $null and $null is lower then the current Time. so you need to check that the lastlogontime is not null

change the if to this:

```
if($lastlogontime -ne $null -and $lastlogontime -lt $time)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried but even though the user has logon before but it still looping to user has not logged in before and I have checked the lastlogontime is not null. Please advice.

Comment: Hey @Nyleve, Have you set the $time parameter? I didnt include it in my script as I sew in your script you already included it.. if no, in the second line, add $time = get-date . Let me know if it helped you.